# Push after removing folder from index taking over an hour

Tags: git

I am working with a remote repository that included a folder / sub-folders of external libraries with over 5000 files.

I've added this folder to gitignore and removed from the index with

```
git rm -r --cached <foldername>
```

Then commited and pushed (in VS Code). The push has been running for over an hour (VS code shows spinner and 'syncing changes' message).

Git log shows no output.

What is actually happening during a push of removed folder in terms of data being synced?
Is there a more efficient way to do the process of removing / pushing changes for a large folder?

Comment: Didn't you make a `commit` before `git rm` ?

Comment: I didn't, it was a new branch. Process was - create branch from master. Run 'rm' command on new branch, commit then push.

Comment: I guess you can not unless you delete this folder (to make a change to the repo). `git ignore` won't work because the folder already belongs to the repo

Comment: That's why I ran 'rm'. to remove it from the repo, then going forward it will be ignored. As I understand it.

Comment: running `rm` will remove the changes from the index,  but literally deleting the folder will be remove it locally and pushing will remove it from remote repo

Comment: Git docs tell me 'rm' removes the files from the index. I understand this to mean they  will no longer be tracked / included in the repository. This is what I want to happen. Then pushing will update the remote repository to the same, i.e. folder now not in remote repo. I do not want to literally delete the folder. Just to have it out of the repository / untracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was false reporting by VS Code. Remote repository shows changes are committed while VS still showed syncing message. Should have checked this earlier!

Comment: I do recommend use cmd with git not the IDEs